# .htaccess Rediret dynamic url to custom url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have a URL structure like this

`localhost/sumar/gallery.php?gen=slug-here`

that i want to clean up for example: `localhost/sumar/gallery/slug-here`

so i need rewrite rule for this condition and prevent anyone from directly hitting the base URL `http://localhost/sumar/gallery.php?gen=slug-here` by auto redirecting it to `localhost/sumar/gallery/slug-here`

So far i have tried this method:

```
//that works

RewriteRule ^Gallery/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ gallery.php?gen=$1 

//below one does not seems to work

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /sumar/gallery\.php\?gen=([\w-]+) [NC]    
RewriteRule ^sumar/gallery\.php$ /sumar/Gallery/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What is the directory structure?

Comment: all the files including .htaccess are on the root

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to act on the raw requests:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(sumar)/Gallery/([\w-]+)/?$ /$1/gallery.php?gen=$1

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /sumar/gallery\.php\?gen=([\w-]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^sumar/gallery\.php$ /sumar/Gallery/%1? [R=301,L]
```

PS: The character set `[A-Za-z0-9_]` can be represented with `\w`.

Comment: thanks but it is not working, Actually i have a URL structure like this http://localhost/sumar/gallery.php?gen=sumar-shop that i want to clean up for example: http://localhost/sumar/gallery/sumar-shop so i need rewrite rule for this condition and prevent anyone from directly hitting the base URL "gallery.php" by auto redirecting it to */gallery/.

Comment: @RahmanQaiser: Change last line to `RewriteRule ^gallery\.php$ /sumar/Gallery/%1? [R=301,L]` but you should've provide this information in question